# Provision for handling equal values when asserting collection order with NUnit

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

**Scenario:**

I am using `Assert.That(values, Is.Ordered.Descending)` where `values` is a list of DateTimes in string format.

**Expected outcome:**

Sequential values that have the same `string` value are treated as valid by the ordering function.

**Actual outcome:**

Duplicates/sequential values with the same value are not allowed and an exception is thrown.

Is there a built in option/parameter that would allow me to specify that equal/duplicate values are ok?

Comment: Try the ExpectedException (attribute) of a custom exception type that handles the duplicate values.

Comment: Hi @GrantWinney is your NUnit version greater than 2.5? See the bottom of http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=collectionConstraints&r=2.5.10.

Comment: Sorry @GrantWinney I have typed correctly it correctly in Visual Studio but failed when transcribing it into my question. I have updated the question with the correct syntax.

Comment: Thanks for your help @GrantWinney. It looks like it isn't possible at this stage so I have implemented my own method.

Comment: Is this NUnit 3? I wonder if this is a bug, rather than intentional behaviour...it sounds less than ideal! Maybe worth a bug report: https://github.com/nunit/nunit

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing there is no overload/method to specify that duplicate values are okay as part of the sequence.

I have written my own method to handle this case.

```
private void AssertColumnIsOrderedByDateDescending(int columnIndex)
    {
        Dictionary<int, ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement>> tableData = Driver.GetTableData(IssuesTableBodySelector);
        DateTime previousDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);

        foreach (ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> webElements in tableData.Values)
        {
            string dateTimeString = webElements.ElementAt(columnIndex).Text;

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dateTimeString))
                continue;

            DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Parse(dateTimeString);

            Assert.LessOrEqual(currentDate, previousDate);

            previousDate = currentDate;
        }
    }
```

In my scenario the issues are only ever created with a retrospective date so `.AddDays(1)` is a viable hack for the start value.